# CORS request failing only when requesting the same resource from another domain

Tags: ajax, cors

When requesting the same remote resource from pages on different hosts the requests succeeds on the first request and on subsequent requests from pages on the same host but fails on pages on another host. I've seen this behaviour both in firefox and chromium but strangely enough not always.

To try it out check out, access these pages in any order:

- http://lodide.io/test-cors.html
- http://test.lodide.io/test-cors.html

After pressing the "Request data" button on the first page you will see a dialog with the contents of the remote resource, if you try to do the same on the other host you might see the following on the browser console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card.rdf.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match
>   'http://test.lodide.io').

It seems that the browser is caching some inferred Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header and then complaining that the new host doesn't match. Note that the server actually return "*" as value of the header.

Is there a way to work around this problem by programmatically disabling caching when issuing the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: You can use IE for cross domain. OR if you are able to change server side code then you can do it.

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam, I don't think you understood the problem. The server is sending back the correct CORS headers, otherwise let me know what you think should be changed on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem you are encountering is that w3.org is not using the `Vary` header, despite varying the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the request. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches.

Comment: Agreed. The response should be using `Vary: Origin` at the very least

Comment: I didn't notice the w3c is only sending back "*" as value of the header when no origin header is present in the request. The response should ether just return "*" or contain a vary-header, but I see no reason for mirroring the Origin header in the Allow-Origin-Header.